# Why is my Azure Function running on a Consumption Plan not scaling?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function that is hooked up to a Service Bus queue. It receives a message and generates records to save in an Azure Table storage.

The Service Bus queue currently has a lot of messages:

[image: Service Bus queue]

Since there are a lot of pending messages, I would expect the scaling of the Azure Functions to happen, however it does not seem to be the case:

[image: Azure Function metrics]

There is only one instance of the Function running and I expected more to help empty the queue.

As specified in the [Azure Function's documentation on scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#understanding-scaling-behaviors) when using a service bus, I made sure the policy used by the Azure Function included the Manage rights to help scaling:

[image: Service bus queue policy]

**Question**

Why is my Azure Function running on a Consumption Plan not scaling to help dequeue all the messages from the Service Bus?

**Update**

Here is an extract of the Azure Function:

```cs
public static class RecordImporter
{
    private static readonly IImporter Importer;

    static RecordImporter()
    {
        Importer = new AzureTableImporter();
    }

    [FunctionName("Importer")]
    public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("records ", Connection = "serviceBusConnectionString")] string serializedRecords, ILogger log)
    {
        var records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Record>>(serializedRecords);
        await Importer.AddRecordsAsync(records);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your Function code/configuration? This does seem a bit odd, normally an SB triggered function should scale up as the scale controller sees more and more messages in the queue..

Comment: @juunas I have included the code of the Azure Function.

Comment: Hi, any update? Can you scale now?

Comment: @BowmanZhu Nope... I wonder if the use of a ServiceBus Queue is the reason why it does not scale... Will try with a Topic instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, because some people face the similar problem with service bus trigger scale out:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6759

I notice you are using C#, so please do this when publish:

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Clear the Run from package file check box. By default, VS uses Zip deployment, which can be changed to Web deployment through the above steps.)